# Update sfdx package in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: sfdx-plugin, pipelines, bitbucket

I'm working on a pipeline to package and deploy sfdc code. I'm attaching the script.

```
# CI process for SFDX
image: radon57/sfdx-cli #image with sfdx installed

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &package_install
        name: Package and Install
        script:
          - apt-get install -y jq  
    
          - export PACKAGE_NAME=$( cat sfdx-project.json | jq -r '.packageDirectories[0].package') 
 
          - sfdx force:package:create --name "$PACKAGE_NAME" --description "My Package"
```

This script works fine for the first time. When I update the code and execute the pipeline, it fails because of the unique package name constraint.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is increment the package version number automatically, every time the pipeline runs. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, just to update the package version, and bypass the unique package name error while creating the package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should consider re-writing your pipeline a little bit. You do not need to create a new `Package2` every time the pipeline runs. Instead, only create `Package2Versions`. The package itself is a one-time setup that is literally required **once** in the whole lifecycle of a second generation package. Absolutely no need to add this to your pipeline.

I also strongly recommend to **not** promote the package version without at least one manual approval step, a deployment on staging, and a full regression test run. This will enable you to iterate faster and safer. Your current pipeline may easily deploy broken code into production (assuming the last step uses a production username).

I recently wrote and open-sourced a CircleCI pipeline that does the following:

- Full scratch org setup including regression test (dependencies), LWC unit tests and test data import
- Deployment on a staging (after manual approval), including unvalidated package build and **full** regression test of all unit tests. This job also [performs an automatic](https://lietzau-consulting.de/2021/12/sfdx-ci-automatic-rollback-on-fail/) rollback, if one step fails
- Deployment on production (after manual approval), using the validated package build, full regression test, package version promotion and automatic rollback

Feel free to use these snippets as a starting point for your pipeline.

I like your idea of automatically incrementing the package version. However, this essentially prevents you from iterating multiple commits on the same package version. Therefore, we opted to manually setup a package version and only automate from there (constantly making new builds, but manually controlling the package version).

Here's a link to the demo repository including the pipeline. The full file's to big to put it here: https://github.com/j-schreiber/1-1-1-setup-template

Here is an excerpt that builds the validated package version asynchronously (huge performance improvement!)

```yml
  build_validated_package:
    executor:
      name: default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - sfdx/install
      - run:
          name: Setup SFDX CLI
          command: |
            echo $SFDX_JWT_KEY | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./server.key
            sfdx auth:jwt:grant --clientid $SFDX_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile server.key --username $USERNAME_PRODUCTION
            mkdir -p force-app
      - run:
          name: Build Production Package
          command: |
            sfdx force:package:version:create -p $PACKAGE_ID -v $USERNAME_PRODUCTION -w 60 -k $INSTALLATION_KEY -c
```

And here's an excerpt that deploys to production (after approval), with automatic rollback:

```yaml
  install_production:
    executor:
      name: default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - sfdx/install
      - run:
          name: Setup SFDX CLI
          command: |
            echo $SFDX_JWT_KEY | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./server.key
            sfdx auth:jwt:grant --clientid $SFDX_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile server.key --username $USERNAME_PRODUCTION
            sfdx auth:jwt:grant --clientid $SFDX_CONSUMER_KEY_STAGING --jwtkeyfile server.key --username $USERNAME_STAGING --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
            mkdir -p force-app
      - run:
          name: Retrieve Originally Installed Package Version For Rollback
          command: |
            output=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -t -q "SELECT SubscriberPackageId FROM Package2 WHERE Id = '$PACKAGE_ID'" -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION)
            SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_ID=$(echo $output | grep -o '033[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
            output=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -t -q "SELECT SubscriberPackageVersionId FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage WHERE SubscriberPackageId = '$SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_ID'" -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION)
            SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID=$(echo $output | grep -o '04t[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
            if [ -z $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID ]; then
                echo "No installed version found. Rollback disabled."
            else
                echo "Storing originally installed package version for rollback: $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID ..."
                echo $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID >> rollback_package_version_id.txt
            fi
      - run:
          name: Install Latest Validated Package (Staging)
          command: |
            query=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -t -q "SELECT SubscriberpackageVersionId FROM Package2Version WHERE Package2Id = '$PACKAGE_ID' AND ValidationSkipped = false ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1" -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION)
            SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID=$(echo $query | grep -o '04t[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
            echo "Installing latest package version: $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID ..."
            sfdx force:package:install -w 10 -b 10 -u $USERNAME_STAGING -p $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID -k $INSTALLATION_KEY -r
      - run:
          name: Deploy Source (Staging)
          command: |
            sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/deploy -u $USERNAME_STAGING -w 10 -l RunLocalTests
      - run:
          name: Promote Latest Build
          command: |
            query=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -t -q "SELECT SubscriberpackageVersionId FROM Package2Version WHERE Package2Id = '$PACKAGE_ID' AND ValidationSkipped = false ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1" -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION)
            SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID=$(echo $query | grep -o '04t[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
            echo "Promoting latest package version: $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID ..."
            sfdx force:package:version:promote -v $USERNAME_PRODUCTION -p $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID -n
      - run:
          name: Install Latest Validated Package (Production)
          command: |
            query=$(sfdx force:data:soql:query -t -q "SELECT SubscriberpackageVersionId FROM Package2Version WHERE Package2Id = '$PACKAGE_ID' AND ValidationSkipped = false ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1" -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION)
            SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID=$(echo $query | grep -o '04t[a-zA-Z0-9]*')
            echo "Installing latest package version: $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID ..."
            sfdx force:package:install -w 10 -b 10 -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION -p $SUBSCRIBER_PACKAGE_VERSION_ID -k $INSTALLATION_KEY -r
      - run:
          name: Deploy Source (Production)
          command: |
            sfdx force:source:deploy -p src/deploy -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION -w 10 -l RunLocalTests
      - run:
          name: Run Apex Tests (Production)
          command: |
            mkdir -p test-results/apex
            set +e
            sfdx force:apex:test:run -w 10 -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION -r junit -d test-results/apex
            exitCode=$?
            rm -f test-results/apex/test-result.xml
            exit $exitCode
      - run:
          name: Rollback To Previous Package Version
          command: |
            ROLLBACK_PACKAGE_VERSION=rollback_package_version_id.txt
            if [ -f "$ROLLBACK_PACKAGE_VERSION" ]; then
                read -r original_package_version < $ROLLBACK_PACKAGE_VERSION
                echo "Rolling back to original package version ... $original_package_version"
                sfdx force:package:install -w 10 -b 10 -u $USERNAME_PRODUCTION -p $original_package_version -k $INSTALLATION_KEY -r
            else
                echo "No package version was installed. Rollback disabled."
            fi
          when: on_fail
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-results
```